# Not able to send payload from github webhook to Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, github-webhook

I am getting "Payload could not be delivered" message when i try to set up webhook at github.

I have installed Jenkins on my EC2 instance on AWS. I have my own repository on github. Now when I try to setup a webhook, I was getting "403 No valid crumb was included in the request". I referred to some articles on internet and set "Enable Proxy compatibility" option in CSRF Protection settings on my Jenkins. Now I am getting another error message saying "We couldn’t deliver this payload: Failure when receiving data from the peer"

What is it that I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: I could resolve this problem with disabling "Enable Proxy compatibility" option in CSRF Protection settings" in configure Jenkins. But, now i am getting "Service unavailable" message. The Jenkins is accessible from internet and github should be able to send payload but I dont know why it is not able to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I was putting the wrong URL in the webhook. Therefore getting this Service Unavailable message. Please note that the webhook should end with /github-webhook/ as a standard, then only Jenkins would be able to accept it.